# Wrapping moving text around screen in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have no idea how to approach this but I was wondering if it would be possible to allow text to wrap around to the other side of the screen as its moving out. For instance:

```
|        |         |        |
|    Text|    ->   |t    Tex| 
|        |         |        |
```

As the 'Text' horizontally moves from left to right

Comment: It's possible to create a marquee, but not easy.  You need a Swing Timer to show the text in a JLabel for X milliseconds, then shift the characters one position to the right, wrapping the text,

Comment: Check out: [Marquee Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/04/24/marquee-panel/). It doesn't do exactly what you want but it may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example.  It's very simple but should help you out. The `INCREMENT` and the `DELAY` control the speed. This gives the illusion of wrapping text by taking advantage of drawing outside the panel where it isn't visible. This is done by drawing two copies of the string at different positions based on `startx`

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Marquee extends JPanel {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Marquee");
    String msg = "AN EXAMPLE OF WRAP AROUND TEXT";
    Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 28);
    int PANELWIDTH = 700;
    int PANELHEIGHT = 100;
    int TEXT_LOC_Y = 50;
    int DELAY=50;      // milliseconds
    int INCREMENT = 2; // amount in pixels to update x loc
    int startx = 0;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Marquee().start());
    }
    
    public void start() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(0, (ae) -> repaint());
        timer.setDelay(DELAY);
        timer.start();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(PANELWIDTH, PANELHEIGHT);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setFont(font);
        g2d.drawString(msg, startx-PANELWIDTH, TEXT_LOC_Y);
        g2d.drawString(msg, startx+=INCREMENT, TEXT_LOC_Y);
        if(startx >= PANELWIDTH) {
            startx = startx-PANELWIDTH-INCREMENT;
        }
        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
```